# How can I get my bougainvillea leave to flower more?

Tags: bougainvillea

My bougainvillea is getting quite big, but I don't get a lot of flowers on it. Does that mean it's getting too much water? I try not to water it at all, but maybe it's getting water from the nearby plants. Please advise.

Here is a photo of my bush. It’s about 10 years old. It has a few blossoms but not like some bougainvilleas.

[image]

Comment: How much direct hot sun does the plant get, in hours, on average? Also please indicate what fertilizer has been applied on this plant or any other plants that the Bougainvillea roots can reach.

Comment: Adding a picture would be helpful.  How old is the tree?

Comment: @ColinBeckingham It gets direct sun most of the day, but I live in San Francisco, so the air is often cool and foggy. However, I've seen plenty of gorgeous bougainvillea bushes in San Francisco with tons of blossoms. I don't use fertilizer much at all. Should I? I thought bougainvillea likes a little neglect.

Comment: @debbiesym - exactly, neglect is good. Your Bougainvillea is rather small for 10 years growth, so it is not getting overfertilized. This plant requires a lot of sun, minimum 6 hours a day, better 8 hours. Curious that it flowers along the bottom, not at top. Is it the lower parts that get lots of sun? Keep pruning for new wood which is where the flowers will come.